# How to place a object without tapping on the screen

Tags: java, kotlin, arcore

I am trying to show an object without tapping on the screen using ARCore. In the basic sample of ARCore Sceneform provided by Google, you need to tap on the screen after it detects the surface.

I want to implement that, AR shows the object without tapping on the screen.

```
Anchor newAnchor;

    for (Plane plane : mSession.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
        if (plane.getType() == Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING)
        {
            newAnchor = plane.createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
            break;
        }
    }
```

I tried this for displaying without tapping on the screen.

if Anyone know how to do this please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @ARGeo please don't add irrelevant tags to the question. This isn't about Kotlin, and tags are supposed to be used for languages and tools relevant *to the question*, NOT known platform-supporting tags or just because an answer uses it. Tag the question, not answers or background context

Comment: Ok @Zoe. I've made it for convenience of readability of Java and Kotlin codes.

Comment: @ARGeo the Android tag adds automatic rendering to both. Explicit highlighting can be done with `<!-- language: lang-kotlin -->` (/`lang-java`, or after the opening three backticks if it uses code fences) in front of the code block if the automatic system fails (or just as a failsafe)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although I suggest you place the object when a user taps & where s/he taps on the screen, what you're asking can be achieved like so. (this example is in Kotlin)

Before you begin placing an object, you need to create a `ModelRenderable`. Declare one `@Nullable` globally.

```
private var modelRenderable: ModelRenderable? = null

//Create the football renderable
ModelRenderable.builder()
                //get the context of the ARFragment and pass the name of your .sfb file
                .setSource(fragment.context, Uri.parse("FootBall.sfb"))
                .build()

                //I accepted the CompletableFuture using Async since I created my model on creation of the activity. You could simply use .thenAccept too.
                //Use the returned modelRenderable and save it to a global variable of the same name
                .thenAcceptAsync { modelRenderable -> this@MainActivity.modelRenderable = modelRenderable }
```

The major chunk of the programming has to be done on the frame's `onUpdate` method. So you attach a listener for frame updates like so

```
 fragment.arSceneView.scene.addOnUpdateListener(this@MainActivity) //You can do this anywhere. I do it on activity creation post inflating the fragment
```

now you handle adding an object on the listener.

```
 override fun onUpdate(frameTime: FrameTime?) {
    //get the frame from the scene for shorthand
    val frame = fragment.arSceneView.arFrame
    if (frame != null) {
        //get the trackables to ensure planes are detected
        val var3 = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane::class.java).iterator()
        while(var3.hasNext()) {
            val plane = var3.next() as Plane

            //If a plane has been detected & is being tracked by ARCore
            if (plane.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

                //Hide the plane discovery helper animation
                fragment.planeDiscoveryController.hide()


                //Get all added anchors to the frame
                val iterableAnchor = frame.updatedAnchors.iterator()

                //place the first object only if no previous anchors were added
                if(!iterableAnchor.hasNext()) {
                    //Perform a hit test at the center of the screen to place an object without tapping
                    val hitTest = frame.hitTest(frame.screenCenter().x, frame.screenCenter().y)

                    //iterate through all hits
                    val hitTestIterator = hitTest.iterator()
                    while(hitTestIterator.hasNext()) {
                        val hitResult = hitTestIterator.next()

                        //Create an anchor at the plane hit
                        val modelAnchor = plane.createAnchor(hitResult.hitPose)

                        //Attach a node to this anchor with the scene as the parent
                        val anchorNode = AnchorNode(modelAnchor)
                        anchorNode.setParent(fragment.arSceneView.scene)

                        //create a new TranformableNode that will carry our object
                        val transformableNode = TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem)
                        transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
                        transformableNode.renderable = this@MainActivity.modelRenderable

                        //Alter the real world position to ensure object renders on the table top. Not somewhere inside.
                        transformableNode.worldPosition = Vector3(modelAnchor.pose.tx(),
                                modelAnchor.pose.compose(Pose.makeTranslation(0f, 0.05f, 0f)).ty(),
                                modelAnchor.pose.tz())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used one extension method

```
//A method to find the screen center. This is used while placing objects in the scene
private fun Frame.screenCenter(): Vector3 {
    val vw = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    return Vector3(vw.width / 2f, vw.height / 2f, 0f)
}
```

This is the end result
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I want the output as you shown in the GIF.
but can you help me to figure out this statement
`fragment.arSceneView.arFrame`

Comment: `fragment.arSceneView.arFrame` calls the java method `getArFrame()` in `ArSceneView` class. It is used to retrieve the latest frame from the camera feed that will be used to perform our hit test or whatever. Java equivalent would be `<fragmentName>.getArSceneView().getArFrame()`

Comment: I did that just to showcase. Don't have it anymore.

Comment: okk, but when I am trying to add this `fragment.arSceneView.scene.addOnUpdateListener(this@MainActivity)` as `fragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame().addOnUpdateListener(MainActivity.this)` it won't work and I also tried this in kotlin

Comment: `addOnUpdateListener` is only available in SceneForm v1.4. Upgrade your library, it ought to start working.

Comment: `private Vector3 Frame.screenCenter() {
        View vw = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        return Vector3(vw.width / 2f, vw.height / 2f, 0f);
    }`

I am getting an error with this

Comment: That is an extension method in Kotlin. Convert that into a standard Java method something similar to this :
`private Vector3 getScreenCenter() {
View vw = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
return Vector3(vw.width / 2f, vw.height / 2f, 0f);
}`

And use it like so : 

`val hitTest = frame.hitTest(getScreenCenter().x, getScreenCenter().y)`

Comment: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException at line :   Anchor modelAnchor = plane.createAnchor(hitResult.getHitPose());

Comment: Hi @Clinkz I tried you example and it worked well. Unless the 3d model was added multiple times (At every plane detection I guess). So I added a condition at the begining of onUpdate method so it's only called once when first model has been placed.
The only problem is when i do that i sometimes has black planes appering on my screen. I look like this : https://www.casimages.com/i/181216031121578258.jpg.html

Can you help me on that ?

Comment: @Clinkz I using Sceneform v1.6 but the `addOnUpdateListener` also dont have this method

Comment: @Clinkz any equivalent method for this??

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `hit-testing` or `button's action` methods for placing an object in a real environment, you can use, for instance, a camera's Pose for auto-placement (remember, you have to add an `ARAnchor`, its corresponding `Node` and a `Renderable` in front of the ARCamera i.e. along `-Z` direction):

```
if (this.anchorNode == null) {

    Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();

    float[] position = { 0, 0, -0.75 };       // 75 cm away from camera
    float[] rotation = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };

    Anchor anchor =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));

    anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
    anchorNode.setRenderable(yourModelRenderable);
    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet if you want to place only one object.. Thanks @clinkz

```
override fun onUpdate(frameTime: FrameTime?) {
    arFragment?.let { fragment ->
        fragment.arSceneView?.let { sceneView ->
            sceneView.arFrame?.let { frame ->
                if (!placed) {
                    val trackable = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane::class.java).iterator()
                    if (trackable.hasNext()) {
                        val plane = trackable.next() as Plane
                        if (plane.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                            fragment.planeDiscoveryController?.hide()
                            val hitTest =
                                frame.hitTest(frame.screenCenter().x, frame.screenCenter().y)
                            val hitTestIterator = hitTest.iterator()
                            if (hitTestIterator.hasNext()) {
                                val hitResult = hitTestIterator.next()
                                val modelAnchor = plane.createAnchor(hitResult.hitPose)
                                val anchorNode = AnchorNode(modelAnchor)
                                anchorNode.setParent(sceneView.scene)

                                val transformableNode =
                                    TransformableNode(fragment.transformationSystem)
                                transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
                                transformableNode.renderable = this@ARActivity.modelRenderable

                                transformableNode.worldPosition = Vector3(
                                    modelAnchor.pose.tx(),
                                    modelAnchor.pose.compose(
                                        Pose.makeTranslation(
                                            0f,
                                            0.05f,
                                            0f
                                        )
                                    ).ty(),
                                    modelAnchor.pose.tz()
                                )
                                placed = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun Frame.screenCenter(): Vector3 {
    val vw = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    return Vector3(vw.width / 2f, vw.height / 2f, 0f)
}
```